# UILongPressGestureRecognizer on UISwitch does not fire

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, uiswitch

Today I tried to add an additional `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to an `UISwitch`, which did not really work. My code is the following:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:)];
[lpgr setDelaysTouchesBegan:YES];
[lpgr setDelaysTouchesEnded:YES];
[lpgr setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];
[self.switcher addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
```

in the `viewDidLoad` method of the `viewController` that is the parent `viewController` of that switch. (the switcher is an instance variable, set through a storyboard. The `IBOutlet` is set properly from the UISwitch to the switcherProperty of its viewController).

On a couple of other controls (like a `UIButton, UISlider, UIStepper` and so on) this works, even without the touches cancelled or delayed, and perfectly triggers the target method. However, with my switch, it refuses that behavior.

I have tried removing any other gestureRecognizer on the UISwitch by iterating through all gestureRecognizers on that switch and calling `[switcher removeGestureRecognizer: ... ]`, I´ve also set all of them to require my longPressGestureRecognizer to fail. Other types of gestureRecognizers don´t fire as well.

As far as I understand, GestureRecognizers will receive touches, before the view or control, which they belong to, receives them. Thus, `setCancelsTouchesInView:YES` and `setDelaysTouchesInView:YES` should enable the gestureRecognizer to handle every single gesture until it fails or succeeds, without the view knowing, right?

--------------EDIT------------------

The whole content of my method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(edit:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];

lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(edit:)];
[self.button addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];

lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(edit:)];
[self.slider addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];

lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(edit:)];
[self.segmentedControl addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];

lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(edit:)];
[self.switcher addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];

lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(edit:)];
[self.stepper addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
}
```

As I said, for the other controls this is working, only the switch does not want to work

Comment: I guess the issue is here: [self.switcher setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]; You disabled the interactions, which probably (I'm not absolutely sure) affects the gesture recognizers too.

Comment: Sorry, actually that was only a test after I tried without that line. It did not work before as well

Comment: @TAKeanice: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: I don’t recall what this was for, so I can’t look it up. But I am afraid not. Do you encounter the same? If you find a solution, surely many people will benefit if you link it here!

Answer (score 0):

try with it

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

// Disallow recognition of tap gestures in the segmented control.
if ((touch.view == yourSwitch)) {//change it to your condition
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

make sure you confirm `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` for it to work.

Comment: Why should I not let the gestureRecognizer receive my touch? That is exactly the opposite of what I want. My gestureRecognizer attached to my switch does NOT receive the touches it should receive. I have not set a delegate for my gestureRecognizer, and the default value if the method is not implemented is YES.

Comment: Also, I don´t subclass UISwitch, so if I want to be the delegate of its other gestureRecognizers, I would have to set their delegate. That should have the same effect as removing them entirely, which I tried.